# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-\frac{2\pi}{n}} e^{-2\pi n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum

> I need a closed form for $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-\frac{2\pi}{n}} e^{-2\pi n}$$
> where $x\in[1,\infty)$

For $x=1$ we have the sum as $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2\pi n}=\frac{1}{e^{2\pi}-1}$$

For $1<x<\infty$ we can write the sum as $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^{\frac{1}{n}} e^n)^{-2 \pi} $$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like it can be answered using a Fourier series. I am not sure though.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Ohk. Thank you. Please give some idea so that how to use fourier series in this question.

Comment: Because of the power $1/n$, I doubt that there is a closed form.

Comment: I agree with @gary and bet there's no closed form. In a pinch you can get an approximation by replacing the sum with an integral: $\int_0^\infty\, x^{-2\pi/\xi}e^{-2\pi\xi}\, d\xi =  2\sqrt{\log x}K_1(4\pi\sqrt{\log{x}})$.